# How to deploy and configure nextjs (using reactjs) application on cloudways or debian OS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to deploy my Next.js (React.js) application and make it runnable for cloudways server:

I tried following command in visual studio code terminal.

```
npx create-next-app
```

When above command is executed, I created following pages and components.

`_app.js`

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
export default MyApp;
```

`index.js`

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.scss";    
import Layout from "../components/layout/layout";    
export default function Home(initialData) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Head>
                <title>Test/title>
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <Layout></Layout>
        </div>
    );
}
```

`layout.js`

```
import Nvbr from "../navbar";
import React from "react";
export default function Layout(props) {
    debugger;
    return (
        <>
            <Nvbr />
            <main role="main">
                {props.preContainer && props.preContainer}
                <div className="album py-5 bg-light">
                    <div>{props.children}</div>
                </div>
            </main>               
        </>
    );
}
```

`nvbr.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { Nav, Button, Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Nvbr() {
    return (
        <>
            <Nav className="py-3 px-4 navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
                <div className="container-fluid">                    
                    <div className="navbar-toggler">                        
                        <button aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" type="button" aria-label="Toggle navigation" className="navbar-toggler collapsed">
                            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div className="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <div className="ml-auto">
                            <div className="ic_top_nav justify-content-end navbar-nav">
                                <Link href="/">
                                    <a className="nav-link nav-link" data-rb-event-key="2">
                                        Home
                                    </a>
                                </Link>
                                <Link href="/about">
                                    <a className="nav-link nav-link" data-rb-event-key="3">
                                        About Us
                                    </a>
                                </Link>                               
                                <Link href="/contact">
                                    <a className="nav-link nav-link" data-rb-event-key="8">
                                        Contact
                                    </a>
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </Nav>
        </>
    );
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "lint": "next lint",
        "export": "npm run build && next export -o _static"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
        "next": "11.0.1",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2",
        "react-icons": "^4.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "7.29.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "11.0.1"
    }
}
```

`next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
};

const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    distDir: "build",
    sassOptions: {
        includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, "styles")],
    },
};
```

After that, I executed the following command

```
npm run build -prod
```

Following response came after the command execution,

```
test@0.1.0 build E:\test\Git\test\nextjs\amica
> next build

info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - Checking validity of types
info  - Creating an optimized production build
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data  
info  - Generating static pages (5/5) 
info  - Finalizing page optimization

Page                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                             374 B          89.9 kB
├   /_app                         0 B            63.6 kB
├ ○ /404                          3.17 kB        66.8 kB
├ ○ /about                        3.78 kB        95.9 kB
├ λ /api/data                     0 B            63.6 kB
├ λ /api/hello                    0 B            63.6 kB
└ ○ /contact                      1.28 kB        93.4 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all     63.6 kB
  ├ chunks/framework.923004.js    42 kB
  ├ chunks/main.a3a79a.js         20.2 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app.33e666.js   570 B
  ├ chunks/webpack.61095c.js      810 B
  └ css/e9c443dd09903fafb4e8.css  37 kB

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
   (ISR)     incremental static regeneration (uses revalidate in getStaticProps)
```

This works fine when I create a pure React.js application but Next.js display only a blank page.

Is there a way to set up a pattern for Next.js to deploy an application in cloudsways or some other servers?

I tried all know ways (by reading articles from https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment and google) but it couldn't be available in the browser.

Comment: "but nextjs display only a blank page" - do you get any errors at all when accessing the app in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nextjs has 2 steps. build and start.

```
npm run build
```

will give you the build folder. However, to run the application, you would need to run

```
npm run start
```

However, it will start the application at port 3000. To test if the application is running, run `curl localhost:3000` in the machine with another terminal and you should see the return.

Then you need to follow the [article](https://www.thecloudkeeper.io/how-to-host-a-nodejs-app-on-cloudways/) to install pm2 in the cloudway server and start the service using pm2.

This [guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment) should also give some hints if you still have errors.